# Cant use Find_element_by_id in selenium ,python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm  a beginner and trying to learn Selenium with python , while everyone can use find_element_by_id() and many more attributes , my system is showing only 2 attributes that is - find_element() and find_elements() , please help on how to use them

[This image shows what i am seeing in my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skYF6.png)

[This is what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZGER.png)

please help

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_id` is deprecated in the latest version of selenium.

You can use the following code to get the equivalent result of that

```
element = driver.find_element("id", "element_id")
```

Or,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")
```